# What's the difference between "could", "may" and "might"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

I knew that these auxiliary verbs mean the low possibility though. Should I use this one?

For example:

> Even if you can not pick up English...
>
> 1. you **might** **be** able to work abroad.
> 2. you **may be** able to work abroad
> 3. you **could** work abroad.

Which one is correct?

Comment: In future questions like this one, it might be better to ask, "Which of these are correct?" (When you ask "Which one is correct?" it sounds like you think one of them is correct and the rest of them are therefore incorrect. Oftentimes – as in this case – all of them are correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native English speakers tend to use all these auxiliary/modal verbs without giving a thought to which is most appropriate. The choice depends largely on preference and on the context.

**May** is generally associated with seeking or giving authority/permission and with uncertainty.

> May I say something?
>
> Yes, you certainly may.

**Can** is associated more with ability/skills.

> Can you finish the job today?
>
> I may not be able to.

**Could** and **might** are both used mainly after a main verb in the past tense and before conditions. So:

> He says he may go this weekend

(often) becomes:

> He said he might go this weekend.

And we often say things like:

> I could do it if I had the tools

and

> I might go to the beach if the sun shines.

So **you may be able to work abroad** and **you might be able to work abroad** mean exactly the same thing but the latter works better after a main verb in the past tense.

**You can work abroad** states that you have either the skills or the go-ahead (or both) to do so.

**You could work abroad** would generally (but not always) be used before a condition although a speaker might well say this in response to a question.

> I can't find work in this country.
>
> Well, you could work abroad.

However, there are whole books on the usage of these verbs and you will find guidance at numerous sites including these:

https://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs-can-could-may-might-must.aspx

https://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs-can-could-may-might-must.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> you **might be able** to work abroad

This shows that you won’t certainly be able to work abroad. You might but it is not a 100% possibility.

> you **may be able** to work abroad

Means the same thing, it is not certain that you can work abroad.

> you **could** work abroad

Also indicates uncertainty that you may not be able to work abroad.

**Can** indicates certainty:

> You can **work** abroad

Comment: What is "uncertainty that is not certain".  That's not very clear.

Comment: @JamesK Made it cleared